# Expose webapp to the web?

Tags: java, apache, web-applications

I have a running webapp on localhost:80. How can I now expose it to the internet?
I use tomcat, and can access my localhost ip from network fine!

But if I try to connect to my internet-ip, I only get timeouts.

How can I access my app from the web?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You probably have a router where you need to do port forwarding. Or firewall settings interfere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure your router (ie the device connecting your local network to the internet) to forward incoming TCP connections on port 80, to port 80 on the machine running Tomcat.

This will be much easier if the internal IP of your Tomcat machine is static, if you allocate IP addresses internally using DHCP then you will need to keep the port-forwarding rule updated as the IP changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing from local network. You need to open 80 port from your routersettings using 'port forwarding' tcp/udp 80 to your local ip (i.e. 10.0.0.132)

Answer (score 0):

you need to port forward requests in the router,,

:80 ==> (forward-this-to) ==> :80

after this when you request internet address guy be forwarded to your machine by the router and the request will be answered.